# Finding the average date given an array of PHP DateTime Objects

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime, average

I have an array of PHP DateTime objects:

```
$dates = [
    new DateTime('2019-08-15'),
    new DateTime('2019-08-19'),
    new DateTime('2019-08-20')
];
```

What I would like to receive from this array is the **average date**, which in my calculation would be `2019-08-18`.

Is there a simple way of doing this without breaking down the date parts for each item and finding the average of all of them and then splicing it back together?

Thank you!

Comment: I found quite a few possible solutions on Google. [Here is one of them...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9284279/1415724), will that do? This found using the following keywords on Google search "get an average of dates php".

Comment: Am I the only one who finds the concept of an "average date" to be ... odd?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - Not a solution -- this is finding the average time between two dates, not the average of dates. Completely different question. I came across about a dozen that answer THAT question, but nothing even remotely close to what I actually need.

Comment: @PatrickQ We have "Estimated Receive Date" on multiple items in a purchase order. These days can vary. In lieu of showing each individual item or a huge string of the range, or any other thing, we thought it would be prudent to find an average delivery date for summary purposes. "This is the average date in which to expect most of the items to be delivered at your work location"

Comment: Oh I see. Ok, well I stand corrected then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have no choice other than to iterate over all the values and summing them (using timestamps is the most efficient way), taking the average and then converting that value back to a date:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', array_reduce($dates, function ($c, $d) {
    return $c + $d->format('U');
}, 0)  / count($dates));
```

An alternate way would be to find the difference between each of the dates and the first date in the array, and then take the average of those values and add it to the first date:

```
$days = 0;
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $days += $dates[0]->diff($date)->days;
}
$days = intdiv($days, count($dates));
$avg_date = (clone $dates[0])->modify("+$days days");
echo $avg_date->format('Y-m-d');
```

In both cases the output is:

```
2019-08-18
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hoQ4W)